# Best technique to crop a real-time plot to the chart time interval with D3.js and Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts, real-time-data

I'm implementing a real-time chart with D3.js in Angular. The points are created from a buffer that is continuously fed by events arriving from a websocket connection, and the chart window is continuously shifted as time passes by. Furthermore I implemented features like zooming and panning which can change the window time interval.

All in all I have an array containing the points and a window representing a given time interval.

Currently I'm applying a filter directly on the points:

```
points = this.realtimeService.events
              .filter( (e: { ts: any; value: any; }) => {
                  return ( moment.utc(e.ts).isAfter(this.windowStartTime) &&
                           moment.utc(e.ts).isBefore(this.windowStopTime) );
               })
              .map( (e: { ts: any; value: any; }) => {
                  return { x: this.xScale(moment.utc(d.ts)), y: this.yScale(d.value) }
               });
```

This actually works, meaning that the chart is plotted correctly and I don''t have points or lines going outside the plot area.

The problem is in the way the chart is plotted. I'm using the d3.line() function, which basically requires at least 2 points to draw a line. Sometimes two consecutive points are far in time. Thus, if I only have 1 or worse no points inside the window time interval, nothing is plotted.

[image]

I was also checking a technique that makes use of the scaleTime

```
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([this.windowStartTime, this.windowStopTime])
            .range([this.chartXMin, this.chartXMax]);
```

with the default "clamping" option, but I'm not sure this is what I want.

Is there anyway to apply some "cropping" directly on the svg path which is created by the D3 plotting function

```
d3.select("#path-id")
          .attr('d', this.pointsToLineFunction(points);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can crop an SVG path using **clipping**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking

The steps are:

1. Create a [`<clipPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) element containing the shape of the cutout, for you a rectangle.
2. Set the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path) attribute on the element(s) you want to crop.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes I was exploring the clipPath feature, it actually works. I'm just struggling with the 'translate' attribute to get control over positioning. my chart has a margin, and although I'm applying a translate on the plot area, the clipPath is cropping out a stripe corresponding to 0<y<5..
in general I find very difficult to get control over positioning of every element of the chart, including axes, plot area, etc. Also I'm embedding the chart in an Angular component, which is responsive, which possibly makes things worse..